# Connect Expo React Native App to Salesforce Community

Tags: reactjs, react-native, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am trying to login into a salesforce community from an Expo React Native Project I have created. Does anyone have any examples of how I could go about logging into a Salesforce Community via custom login page i've created in React Native.

I've set a connect app in my org and using that to try and authenticate into Salesforce.

My understanding is that Expo does not support the salesforce mobile sdk, so I'm going down the route connect via the API.

Any help would be appreciated.

` const loginToSalesforceCommunity = async () => {

```
    try {
      const payload = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'MY CLINET ID',
        client_secret: 'MY Client Secret',
        username: email,
        password: password
      };
  
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://MYCOMMUNITYURL.com/s/login/services/oauth2/token',
        payload,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      );
  
      // Handle the successful login response here
      console.log('Access Tokensss:', response.data);
      console.log('Access Tokenss:', response.data.access_token);
      console.log('Access Token:', response.data.access_token);
      console.log('Instance URL:', response.data.instance_url);
      setAuthStatus('authenticated');
      setAuthError(null);
      // Proceed with further actions, such as navigation or API calls
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the login error here
      console.error('Login Error:', error);
      setAuthStatus('unauthenticated');
      setAuthError('Failed to login. Please check your credentials.');
    }
  };
```

`
Error Invalid request, post must use JSON